Reducing cold start in a python AWS Lambda Function
I have an AWS lambda function written in python that needs a way of manipulating data stored in tables.  My solution is to use pandas to read the tables in as parquet files.  While this works, the cold start of this lambda function goes from ~400ms to 2000ms as soon as I add a pandas layer (even without any computation).  I am wondering if there's any options out there that will get my cold start time to less than 1000ms?  The total computation time of this function is <100ms, so it's a shame to have it so inflated.

Do you know how that time breaks down in terms of time spent importing pandas vs time spent loading your parquet files?

Presume you have researched the common options such as provisioned concurrency, minimal pandas packaging (if that's a thing), increase RAM size, profile execution with Lambda power tuning, use arm64, find an alternative to pandas. Pandas et al are not your friends when it comes to low-latency FaaS.

Also, literally announced yesterday, AWS Lambda now supports SnapStart for Python runtimes.

Pandas is a powerful but heavy library. Since cold start time depends on the size of the deployment package (including the layer size), consider using a Lighter alternative, like:
Polar which is a much faster and lighter DataFrame library with similar functionality to Pandas
PyArrow a lightweight and optimized for working with Parquet files and Arrow tables.
If Pandas is necessary, Try to reduce the Lambda layer and exclude any unnecessary files like 'tests, documentations'
Also cold start is primarily caused because of the initialisation time, so you can use AWS Lambda provisioned concurrency, which will keep some instances of your function warm and ready to serve traffic without a cold start penalty, but you need to put in your consideration that this feature is paid, and not for free.

Thanks.  yeah, I am trying as much as possible to avoid provisioned concurrency as I'm trying to lean into the benefits of serverless here.  It would be interesting to see what the differences in cold start time are between the different packages.
